# How to execute php code once on single page view

Tags: php

I have a web page on which four ads are displayed using different ad code for each advertisement. This ad code records website hit and ad impression in two different mysql tables on every time this code is executed.

But my problem is that as i have installed four ads on single web page. whenever this web page is loaded each ad code records website hit in table and ad impression in another table. I want to record website hit once for single web page view whether there exists one ad or more ads. How to do this?

I tried to use session cookie as give below

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['userstatus'])){
    $oldnew = "old";
}
else
{
    $oldnew = "new";    
}

//SESSION DOES NOT EXISTS USER IS NEW AD ROW, IF USER IS OLD DO NOTHING
if(($oldnew == 'new')) {

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO webimps (zoneweb, session, time, ref, device, visitorip, os, oldnew, browser, wview) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssssss", $web, $session, $time, $ref, $device, $ip, $user_os, $oldnew, $user_browser, $one);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

}
```

But this also did not worked, Website hit is recorded by each ad code on single page view.

Comment: you can start by showing some code, no?

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Please add some code samples, it's almost impossible to find out a solution. Why you can't prevent your ads code samples to send several requests?

Comment: There are a lot of unknown variables in example code. Is it possible to fetch from db with all this params to check was this row persisted before? Where are you setting cookie? Is it possible to use session, not cookie for your task?

Comment: these variables are just visitor details like os, ip, browser, etc. these are working fine. But the problem is that each code inserts a new row in database

Answer (score 0):

In your code I don't see `session_start();` If you don't have that in your actual code you should try adding it.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
```

Comment: Earlier I also tried session instead of cookie. But this also not works.